# Dotnet inside Docker behind NGINX giving Connection Refused error

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, nginx-reverse-proxy, kestrel-http-server

Trying to put DOTNET project behind the NGINX. It works ok being accessed directly with -p 8081:8081.
But being behind nginx, it tries to connect itself inside docker container using external url and gets System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Connection refused.

nginx settings looks like:

```
    server {

        listen 443 ssl http2;

        server_name     asvbr;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_certificate  /etc/nginx/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/cert.key;

        underscores_in_headers on;
        large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;

        location / {
            resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off  valid=30s;

            #kill cache
            add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
            add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
            if_modified_since off;
            expires off;
            etag off;

            proxy_set_header    Upgrade     $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header    Connection  keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header    Connection  "Upgrade";            
            proxy_set_header    host        $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; 
            set $asvbr_backend_servers  asv-br_asv-br;
            proxy_pass http://$asvbr_backend_servers:8081;
        }

    }
```

Here is console messages

```
[2023-05-04T13:46:33.259Z] Information: Normalizing '_blazor' to 'https://asvbr/_blazor'.
blazor.server.js:1 [2023-05-04T13:46:33.315Z] Information: WebSocket connected to wss://asvbr/_blazor?id=Hv-fSHSk_-dobtiI41vOqQ.
blazor.server.js:21 [2023-05-04T13:46:33.342Z] Error: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Connection refused (asvbr:443)
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (111): Connection refused
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|283_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

collected network dump inside dotnet container and see, that it tries to access itself as it is goes from users' network via nginx:
[traffic dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTYfE.png)

Is there a way to make it know it's real url inside the container?

Answer (score 0):

added in docker-compose.yml:

```
   additional_hosts:
        - "asvbr:host-gateway"
```

It created a line in /etc/hosts with the service name bound to the host's internal IP address. So when the backend service calls itself, it goes to the host's IP address, gets redirected to nginx through the ingress overlay network, and reaches itself successfully.